# NVL on a date in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In postgres how can i do something like this? i.e. An NVL on a date.

```
SELECT *
FROM payments.transactionreconciliationvicroads
WHERE settlementdate = coalesce(to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),CURRENT_DATE)-1;
```

This doesn't seem to be quite right?

Comment: `to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD')` will never be null. You don't need the `coalesce()`

Comment: But why do you think this "isn't quite right"? `coalesce()` is the standard SQL equivalent to Oracle's `nvl()`

Comment: you probably meant `coalesce(settlementdate,CURRENT_DATE) = to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') -1 `?..

Comment: sorry guys. I should have explained better. '2017-10-01' is actually a parameter that can be nullable and the expression above actually works. For some reason my db client last night was telling me it wasn't. I'm going to close this in response to this.

Comment: Local issue caused the expression not to work